# Powershell Array Modfication with IF

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

im fairly new to Powershell and struggle a bit with the correct array functions.

Basically I just have a list of dates (already in datetime-format) and want to check if any of them is either Sunday or Saturday. If so I need to modify the value in the array using .adddays(1) or (2) to get to the next work day. Afterwards these modified values are the input for an external REST request.
Not sue if FOR or FOREACH is the right way to got and how to correctly assign new values based on IF result.

e.g.:

'''$days = *array of dates*'''

Friday, 15 December 2017 23:00:00
**Sunday, 15 December 2019 23:00:00**  -> .adddays(1)
Tuesday, 15 September 2020 23:00:00
**Sunday, 15 December 2019 23:00:00**  -> .adddays(1)
Tuesday, 1 December 2020 23:00:00
Tuesday, 8 December 2020 23:00:00
**Sunday, 13 December 2020 23:00:00**  -> .adddays(1)
Tuesday, 15 December 2020 23:00:00
Wednesday, 16 December 2020 23:00:00
Thursday, 17 December 2020 23:00:00
Friday, 18 December 2020 23:00:00
**Saturday, 19 December 2020 23:00:00**  -> .adddays(2)
Wednesday, 23 December 2020 23:00:00
Wednesday, 30 December 2020 23:00:00
Wednesday, 13 January 2021 23:00:00
Wednesday, 27 January 2021 23:00:00

Comment: If the array is already datetimes, could you not just check `DayOfWeek`?

Comment: yes. that much i figured already. I can can make the whole thing do a comparison and write an output based on that. But what I dont succeed in is to make the .adddays-modification to the affected dates and have it permanently stored again in the array

Comment: You might need to include some code so we can have more context. I am still not sure why you need to use `AddDays()` here.

Comment: its the requirement. There will be a external REST request to hand over these dates to another application. However, it should only happen for weekdays. If its not a weekday then the following weekday should be used.

Comment: The problem is, i dont know how to modify elements of an array. I get an IF statement to work, but afterwards the array contains exactly the same value for the elements in  question as before.